# Pass props to child component - React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-props

I want to pass props `color` to a icon child.
This `<Feather />` I want to add `color` as props

This is my component and the Feather child

```
import { Feather } from '@expo/vector-icons'

export default class CloseButton extends React.PureComponent {
  render () {
    const { style, ...props } = this.props
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.close} link {...props} >
        <Feather name='x' size={26} /> // <-- want add color here
      </TouchableOpacity>
    )
  }
}
```

This is my component where I send props thas show in `ThouchableOpacity`

`<Alert.CloseButton onPress={props.onRequestClose} />`

How can pass color in this props and it only show on icon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a prop called `color` for your `CloseButton` component that you pass to the `Feather` component.

```
export default class CloseButton extends React.PureComponent {
  render () {
    const { style, color, ...props } = this.props;

    return (
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.close} link {...props} >
        <Feather name='x' size={26} color={color} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    )
  }
}
```

**Usage**

```
<Alert.CloseButton
  onPress={props.onRequestClose}
  color="red"
/>
```